# How to find out percentage of indexed results in Google with rich snippets?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, rich-snippets

I would like to see how many results have their content marked up with Google showing results with rich snippets.

Is there a site search operator that I could use (site:example.com)?  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if can be done, but  another thing to look into would be something in Google Search Console.

Answer (score 2):

In [Google Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) go to Search Traffic > Search Analytics, then click the filter under 'Search Appearance' and choose Rich Results.

This filter will then show you how many times pages on your site have had impressions or clicks when they are displayed in the SERPS with a Rich Result.

It won't however tell you how many pages are actualy marked up to show Rich Results, just the pages which have appeared to searchers in the SERPS.

You can also go to Search Appearance > Structured Data to see how many pages Google has discovered on your site with schema mark up, and should show any which can trigger Rich Results to display. (However in my experience the number shown here can be much less than what is actually marked up on the site and in fact even displaying in the search results!)